# Azure table service sends random 400 errors bot bot framework application

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework, azure-table-storage

I'm using azure-botbuilder to build a bot application. The bot session state is being managed in azure table storage via this

```
var azureTableClient = new azure.AzureTableClient(environment.config.BOT.TABLE_NAME, environment.config.BOT.STORAGE_NAME, environment.config.BOT.STORAGE_KEY);

var tableStorage = new azure.AzureBotStorage({gzipData: false}, azureTableClient);
```

for certain activities (very hard to track which ones unfortunately) - i'm getting the below error from azure table service

```
Error: Failed to perform the requested operation on Azure Table. Message: The property value exceeds the maximum allowed size (64KB). If the property value is a string, it is UTF-16 encoded and the maximum number of characters should be 32K or less.
RequestId:5b6ad583-6002-002a-62c1-583676000000
```

I'm certainly not storing anything as big as 64 KB in my session. We store a few UUIDS, GUIDs and boolean values in our bot state.

How do i track down these requests which yield the error? Can i over-ride tableStorage in someway to tell me what are the request details being sent that yield such an error. As of now , the table storage is a black box

Answer (score 1):

You can use Azure Storage Explorer to check what is being stored in Azure table storage. It's a free download from here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/features/storage-explorer/

You also have the option of using something like Azure Storage Emulator if you want to run and debug locally: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator.

Answer (score 0):

You should try it on Bot Framework Emulator, instead, you will see log from conversation/activities.